# Image mapped image not fully clickable in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, imagemap

I have the following code (well, with links altered for anonymity) in my page...

```
<a href="http://www.page1.com" ><img usemap="#termsclickable" src="picture.png"  /></a>

<map id="termsclickable" name="termsclickable">
<area shape="rect" coords="750,376,938,409" target="_blank" href="http://www.page2.com" alt="" title=""    />

</map>
```

In Chrome and Firefox I can click anywhere outside the rectangle co-ordinates and be taken to page1,  and click within the co-ords and get page 2,  but in Internet Explorer nothing happens when I click outside the co-ords.

What's odd is that if I right click and click 'Open link' it works.

Has anyone seen this odd behaviour before and knows of a workaround?  Or perhaps something wrong with my syntax?

Comment: Could you not just image map the rest of the image to go to page1?

Comment: I was hoping I would not have to but I will try it.

Comment: I have a hunch wrapping the image in an anchor tag as well as mapping it could have caused a conflict somewhere. I see you've sorted it out though.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to answer my own question so that others can come here to get an answer.

As suggested by @Pete I need to define another area that encompases the whole image, and then list it last in my image map....

```
<a href="http://www.page1.com" ><img usemap="#termsclickable" src="picture.png"  /></a>

<map id="termsclickable" name="termsclickable">
<area shape="rect" coords="750,376,938,409" target="_blank" href="http://www.page2.com" alt="" title=""    />
<area shape="rect" coords="0,0,650,950" href="http://www.page1.com" />

</map>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use the 'default' shape. You can find relevant examples [here](http://www.elated.com/articles/creating-image-maps/).

EDIT: Just copying a relevant example from the linked page:

```
<area   shape="default"
    nohref="nohref" title="Default" alt="Default"/>
```

Comment: I just tried it,  the default shape doesn't work.  I have to define another area that encompases the whole image.

Comment: @MrVimes Note that I've specified nohref in above example so it won't do anything. Try adding relevant href to your example?

Comment: Nick,   I did specify a href :).   IE just doesn't like it.

Comment: Ok :) I've actually just read that IE doesn't support the default shape, so this would not necessarily be the way to go anyway.