# Image maps not working in IE

Tags: wordpress, image, internet-explorer, imagemap

I have searched and can not for the life of me figure out why these images with an image map will not work in internet explorer. here is the code. its two images in wordpress in a side bar and ie wont recognize the maps for some reason.

```
<img src="http://patentnow.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/brochure.gif"    href="http://patentnow.org/brochure-landing/" usemap="#planetmap"></img>
<map name="planetmap">
<area shape=default href="http://patentnow.org/brochure-landing/" target=_blank hreflang="en">
</map>

<img src="http://patentnow.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/ebook2.gif" href="http://patentnow.org/ebook-download/" usemap="#planet"></img>
<map name="planet">
<area shape=default href="http://patentnow.org/ebook-download/" target=_blank hreflang="en">
</map>
```

Comment: have you run your page through the [HTML validator](http://validator.w3.org/)?  I'm not sure `</img>` is valid HTML - `<img>` is a self-closing tag.  That might be causing IE some problems.

Comment: You probably should try removing the `href` attribute on the `img` - that's not valid HTML.

Comment: I know the href isnt valid within the <img> but once i realized it wasnt working within the map I put it in there just in case IE would recognize it. I already removed it and removing </img> didnt change anything

Comment: I checked it with the validator and it passed fine.

    <img src="http://patentnow.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/brochure.gif" alt="brochure" usemap="#planetmap">
    <map name="planetmap">
    <area shape=default href="http://patentnow.org/brochure-landing/" target=_blank alt="brochure" hreflang="en">
    </map>

    <img src="http://patentnow.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/ebook2.gif" alt="ebook" usemap="#planet">
    <map name="planet">
    <area shape=default href="http://patentnow.org/ebook-download/" target=_blank alt="ebook" hreflang="en">
    </map>

Comment: Hmm, ok.  The last comment on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17673467/image-mapped-image-not-fully-clickable-in-ie/17673728#17673728) says IE doesn't support the default shape, though the commenter doesn't specify a source - does it work if you specify a different shape (just to test)?